# Database logon failed error in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, sql-server-2016

I am trying to print crystal report in PDF format , and on my local machine it’s working fine. But when I publish application to the server, it’s giving me error.  I am using VS2015 , SQl Server 2016, IIS 10 and CR version 13.0.17.2096
Anyone please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qZTx.png)

Comment: Have you gave correct login credentials while uploading on server?

Comment: Above comment and also are you even setting report source?

Comment: I have given the correct credentials.I think it is the problem of connection between crystal report and sql server. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Check if SQL Server Client in your server is the same as in your rpt file.

1. On Server open SQL Server Configuration Manager
   [image]
2. Open the .rpt and check if the client used is equal the server client 10.
   [image]
3. If SQL Client is diferent create the new connection in your .rpt.
   [image]